# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation error from wubi

Tags: system-installation, windows, permissions, wubi

I am trying to install ubuntu 14.04 LTS via wubi on windows 7 system. after downloading is complete, in the end I am recieving the error.

```
09-18 15:06 ERROR  root: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\ubuntu\\install\\ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 595, in get_iso
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 441, in download_iso
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\ubuntu\\install\\ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso'.
```

I have downloaded the iso and wubi files and saved on the disk. Every time I run `Wubi.exe`, it downloads the iso file from internet. How can I Install Ubuntu from wubi, with selecting the image from hard disk instead of downloading from internet.

Comment: Wubi hasn't been released for 14.04.1 and running the 14.04 version online will fail. If you want Wubi probably best to use 12.04 but it's better to do a normal dual boot.

Comment: I had installed ubuntu 12.04 but the problem I am facing in this version is with Bluetooth Driver.  Hence I am trying with 14.04 version.

Answer (score -1):

1. Download a full, fresh copy of the Ubuntu Karmic ISO. Put that in a temporary directory.
2. Copy the contents of the Ubuntu Karmic Live CD (the one burned from the ISO) into there. So, now you have the ISO used to make the CD, and the contents of the CD, all in that one directory.
3. Right-click on the ISO. Tell Windows 7 to unblock that file, in spite of it being from another computer
4. Run wubi.exe from the temporary directory as an Administrator.

   [Download it from here](http://people.canonical.com/~evand/wubi/karmic/)

   [Refer this link too](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/521489)

Comment: I hope it works for you too :)

Comment: Karmic is release 9.10. It has been unsupported for a number of years now. Not a good idea to install. Also, it had a critical Wubi bug so not even good for Wubi. Not sure why you would want to recommend that.